# Error with downloading of file with PHP

Tags: php

I use easy script for downloading file from Internet:

```
$file=file_get_contents("url");
file_put_contents('temp.flv', $file);
```

It is good works on my local server, but when I put it on my Internet server my script didn't work with error message:

"failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in /home/virtwww/w_dennyboy-ru_d5bd1633/http/index.php"

I try to use it on a few servers, but it is doesn't work always. I try to use 'copy' function too. Help me please.

Comment: Well, if someone doesn't want you to download **their** files - just stay with it.

Comment: Script good works on my local server and good downloads from internet

Comment: ask to the files owner - why he blocks your downloading.

Comment: You probably misquoted your code, but this line would definitely not downloading anything, on any server: file=file_get_contents("url");

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `allow_url_fopen` is disabled on the remote servers (which is basically standard). I would recommend using curl instead; which is what it is built for. Something like this should work:

```
$url = 'http://example.com';
$fileOut = '/var/www/file.test';
$fh = fopen($fileOut, 'w');
//Create curl resource and execute
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: If it was disabled then you'd get `Warning: fopen() [function.fopen]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in ...`